# Probability that X is less than Y directly from joint CDF?

Tags: probability

Suppose X and Y are arbitrary random variables with joint cdf F. Is it possible to find $P(X<Y)$ or $P(X\le Y)$ directly from F? I think it's easier to think in terms of the equivalent $P(X-Y<0)$, but I'm not sure how to go from there. I know that if X and Y are continuous, we can differentiate the joint cdf to get the joint pdf and we can integrate over that to solve it. But is there a more general way to get it directly from the joint cdf? e.g., what if X or Y is not continuous or discrete?

Comment: What would X be if it's not Conti not discrete?

Answer (score -1):

$\displaystyle \mathbb{P}(X\leq Y)= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{y} f(x,y)dxdy$. Assuming continuous r.v pdf $f(x,y)$

Comment: Thank you for effort, but this does not answer question. Question is specifically about not assuming continuity. If you think this makes question clearer, we can add the integration over density as part of question, but this is not answer. Thank you again for effort. Kind regards.